# Who wins in a situation like this one involving a straight?

Tags: texas-hold-em

My buddy has K3 and i have 45 , the board is AKJ10Q , is this a split pot or does he take it because he is holding a king?

Answer (score 1):

Both of you have Ace high Straight with the best 5 cards, so it is a split pot.

It doesn't matter if the cards are in your hand or on the board.

- the assumption is neither player hit a flush.